# Why will this MIPS assembly program not print the index value (as an integer value) of where the second substring starts in the first substring?

Tags: assembly, mips

Trying to write a MIPS assembly language program that prompts the user to input two strings (each should be no longer than 50 characters including the null terminator). My program should determine whether the second string is a substring of the first. If it is, then my program should print out the first index in which the second string appears in the first. For example, if the first string is “Hello World” and the second string is “lo”, then the program should print out 3, i.e. the starting index of “lo” in “Hello World.” If the second string is not contained in the first string, then my program should print out -1.

Here is the code I made so far:

```
.data

    first_string: .space 51     # Allocate space for the first string (max length 50 + null terminator)

    second_string: .space 51    # Allocate space for the second string (max length 50 + null terminator)

    prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the first string (max 50 characters): "

    prompt2: .asciiz "Enter the second string (max 50 characters): "

    output_message: .asciiz "The second string is a substring starting at index "

    not_found_message: .asciiz "The second string is not a substring."



.text

    .globl main



main:

    # Print prompt for the first string

    li $v0, 4

    la $a0, prompt1

    syscall



    # Read the first string

    li $v0, 8

    la $a0, first_string

    li $a1, 51

    syscall



    # Print prompt for the second string

    li $v0, 4

    la $a0, prompt2

    syscall



    # Read the second string

    li $v0, 8

    la $a0, second_string

    li $a1, 51

    syscall



    # Find the second string in the first string

    la $t0, first_string       # Address of the first string

    la $t1, second_string      # Address of the second string

    li $t2, 0                  # Initialize index to 0



find_substring:

    lb $t3, 0($t0)            # Load a character from the first string

    lb $t4, 0($t1)            # Load a character from the second string



    # Check if the end of the first string is reached

    beq $t3, $zero, not_found



    # Check if the characters match

    beq $t3, $t4, check_substring



    # Characters don't match, increment index and continue searching

    addi $t0, $t0, 1

    addi $t2, $t2, 1

    j find_substring



check_substring:

    # Check if the second string is found

    lb $t3, 0($t1)

    beq $t3, $zero, found_substring



    # Characters match, continue checking

    addi $t0, $t0, 1

    addi $t1, $t1, 1

    j check_substring



found_substring:

    # Print the index where the second string starts in the first string

    li $v0, 4

    la $a0, output_message

    syscall



    li $v0, 1

    move $a0, $t2

    syscall



    j exit



not_found:

    # Print a message indicating the second string was not found

    li $v0, 4

    la $a0, not_found_message

    syscall



exit:

    # Exit the program

    li $v0, 10

    syscall



end of code:
```

But when the code runs, misses the starting index by 1 digit off. Why is that?

Comment: Your question seems to be about the algorithm rather than something about assembly code.  You can try to debug it in assembly but really probably need a good and working version of the algorithm in C or a language that you know to compare with.  Much easier to debug an algorithm in a language you know well, and, any language can search for substrings, so no need to think in assembly to work out an algorithm.